# How to handle this error when referring to an image?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem with the header images of my blog post.
Every time the page refers to the image this error appears:

[image]

Here is my definition of the Post:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        help_text="Unique ID for this specific post across all blog post.",)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY, default=1)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="imgs/blog")
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    context_object_name = "post_list"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def getCategoryStr(self):
        return CATEGORY[self.category][1]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.status == 1 and self.created_on is None:
            self.created_on = timezone.now()
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the part of my template. In the base.html I call `{% load static %}`:

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "generalsite/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block body_block %}
{% if post_list %}
{% for post in post_list %}
{% if post.status == 1 %}
{% if forloop.first %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">{{post.getCategoryStr}}</div>
        {% if post.header_image %}
        <img src="{% static post.header_image.path %}" alt="header_image">
        {% endif %}
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="{% url 'detail' post.pk%}">
                    <h4 class="card-title">{{post.title}}</h4>
                </a>
                <p class="card-text text-muted">{{post.caption}}</p>
            </div>
```

Here I define my media directories:

```py
MEDIA_DIR = BASE_DIR.joinpath("imgs")
BLOG_MEDIA = MEDIA_DIR.joinpath("blog")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [MEDIA_DIR, BLOG_MEDIA, STYLE_DIR]
```

Comment: Please show where you reference the image in your template and your media settings

Answer (score 0):

when placing images in the templates you need to use static files, you have to put {% load static %} at the top of your template and just refer to {% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %} when trying to use inside a  tag.

You can read more about static files in the official Django documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/